# Installing graphics driver in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, terminal, graphics-card, ubuntu-9.10

Specs: AMD Athlon XP 2400+ @ 1987 MHz / 2 x 512MB PC3200 DDR RAM / 128MB GeForce 6200 AGP / WD 160GB IDE HDD / FIC AM37 / DB: XP Pro SP3 & Ubuntu 9.10

Hi all,

I just installed Ubuntu 9.10 (within XP) on my desktop for the first time and I am trying to install the driver for my graphics card. I went to the NVIDIA site to download the Linux 32-bit version of the GeForce 6-series driver, which comes in a .run format. I double click on it and it begins to load in gedit, but it is unsuccessful because the character coding couldn't be detected. I tried running it in Terminal, but permission was denied. So, I searched how to open a .run file and came to [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=194143) where I used the "chmod 755 [filename].run" in Terminal.

Now it can start uncompressing but now I get a new message saying "ERROR: nvidia-installer must be run as root". I have no clue what to do now... since I am a noob. XD

How should I be going about this? Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: 'Run as root' means you have to run the program in administrator privileges. In terminal you can do this with `sudo ./[filename].run`. Be careful in super user privileges... Before doing this try the method that Sathya suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to System->Administration->Hardware
>   Drivers and check the box to enable
>   the restricted drivers for your NVIDIA
>   card if the option is provided.
>
> If the restricted driver remains
>   unactivated after attempting to
>   activate it in the Hardware Drivers
>   dialog, you may not have the
>   appropriate linux headers installed to
>   compile the driver. Ensure that the
>   linux-headers-XXX and
>   linux-restricted-modules-XXX packages
>   are installed, where XXX matches the
>   version of the kernel you are using
>   (linux-image-XXX).
>
> If the activation hangs on
>   download/install dialog, you can
>   install the driver using
>   System->Administration->Synaptic
>   Package Manager, make sure you pick
>   the latest driver version recommended
>   by the "Hardware Drivers" tool and all
>   its dependencies. Go to Hardware
>   Drivers tool and activate the driver
>   you just installed.

( [via](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) )

Comment: Before there was nothing listed, but after doing a massive update to Ubuntu, everything worked out and the driver was installed successfully... Thanks!

Comment: @Wesley - Glad to know everything's fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the file you downloaded.

Go to System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers.

Comment: Before there was nothing listed, but after doing a massive update to Ubuntu, everything worked out and the driver was installed successfully... Thanks!